# Java object oriented confusion

Tags: java, oop

So I sort of understand how object oriented works, but I would like to know if you can do this:

Have an arraylist of a certain type of object, let's say fruit. And let's say we have 5 types of fruit, and when we add to the array list we add one of the 5 types but randomly. Is this possible, if so how would you set it up?

Comment: Can you show us some code ?

Comment: Test it, come back when you have a specific programming question, not a *what will happen if I may do this but I don't want to do it?* question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Set up**

So let's say you have a superclass `Fruit`.

```
public class Fruit
```

Then you've got some classes that use it..

```
public class Apple extends Fruit

public class Pear extends Fruit
```

And if you want to be cheeky..

```
public class Tomato extends Fruit
```

You define your `ArrayList` as

```
List<Fruit> fruit = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
```

and you create a method..

```
public Fruit getNextFruit()
{
    // First create a random number.

    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(5);

    // Then this is where I stop coding.
}
```

**Your mission is..**

And now it's up to you to code the rest. You'll have a random number, and a few different types of `Fruit`. You can do all sorts with this, but the logic should be down to you.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible! Take these three classes (in three different .java files, of course).

```
public class Fruit {}
public class Apple extends Fruit {}
public class Orange extends Fruit {}
```

Now add them to a list.

```
ArrayList<Fruit> basket = new ArrayList<>();
basket.add(new Orange());
basket.add(new Apple());
```

You can do this without problem, because you created a list of `Fruit`. `Apple` **is a** `Fruit`, and an `Orange` **is a** `Fruit`. The **is a** relationship is important.

The following will not work, because an `Orange` **is not an** `Apple`.

```
ArrayList<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();
apples.add(new Orange()); // ERROR!
```

---

**Trivia**

Everything object in Java inherits from the Object class. This mans that you can add ***anything*** to a list of objects.

```
ArrayList<Object> birthday = new ArrayList<>();
birthday.add(new Girlfriend());
birthday.add(new TV());
birthday.add(new Car());
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'm not sure what point you are trying to make.

Comment: For testing purposes, it doesn't have to be in three different files. Just eleminate "public" from all-but-one of the classes, and name the file for the public one.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. If you define the generic type of ArrayList as Fruit, then you can pass anything in like a banana, orange, apple, passionfruit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if all your Objects inherits from a super class Fruit:

```
List<Fruit> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

To this list you can add any kind of fruits, as long the extend the class 'Fruit'.